# How to include html files in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and wanted to know what are some of the ways to include html files in rails-  from public folder, from views folder or any other method if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, You put your view files in app/views/controller_name/action_name.html.erb

Take a look at this to get a better understanding -- http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/

Also consider doing the Rails Tutorial(Hartl), that should get you started in understanding how the framework works.

**Update**

Change your header.html, and rename it to _header.html.erb

in your action_name.html.erb,

write

```
<%= render 'header' %>
```

the _ denotes that it's a partial

Comment: I understand that... I have a different issue, in my views/controller_name, I have to keep a new file header.html along with action_name.erb and then include that header.html via action_name.erb or controller_name.rb Hope u get my issue now... pls help

Comment: Sub, the action_name needs to be in your controllers/controller_name.rb. The html should be in the action_name.html.erb file. You can just paste it in there, and it will interpret correctly. The reason it has a .erb at the end is because you can also optionally write ruby inside the view. Take a look at the rails tutorial, you will learn a lot from it.

Comment: ok, re-writing my previous comment in a different way: in my views/controller_name, I have action_name.html.erb and then I have another file header.html  which I need to include in my controller_name.rb. So, corresponding to controller_name.rb I have action_name.html.erb but header.html is a different file which has to be included too...

Comment: ahhh, one second updating comment

Answer (score 0):

```
@file = render_to_string :file => '/aboslute/path/to/file.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

stop thinking and use jQuery

html

```
  <div id="here"></div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
    $('#here').html("<%= j(render partial: 'profiles/users') %>");
</script>
```